# How to retain data (form) on custom pagination using MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have a grid (list generated using scaffolding option) with search criteria. And I created paging concept. I entered search criteria data and search, after post back, I retained the form data using TempData. But, if I click page numbers in grid, the form data not retained and also the grid also getting refreshed.

*Is there any way to retain data on pagination?*

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're refreshing the entire page. Usually, the new data should update (trough AJAX) a specific portion, i.e. a `div`. This way, you only need to update the grid and not the entire page. The form data would remain unchanged.

Comment: Why don't you post some of the code that you've done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a hidden field dynamically within the form using JavaScript. The page number stored in hidden field, when the user click page number, then submit the form. It is working well without any issue.

Paging:

```
<button onclick="navigateTo(this, '@Url.RouteUrl("Defined_Route", new { currentPage = j })');">@j</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () { //Page Load - Create hidden field, if search button found
    if ($("#search")) // Button id
    {
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "hidden";
        element.id = "currentPage";
        element.name = "currentPage";
        element.value = '@TempData["Page"]';
        if (isNaN(element.value)) element.value = "1";
        $(to).parent().append(element);
    }
});

function navigateTo(field, url)
{
    $("#currentPage").val(field.innerText);
    if (isNaN($("#currentPage").val()))
    {
        location.href = url;//This is for direct url, ie. no search form
    }
    else
    {
        $("form").action = url;
        $("form").submit();
    }
}
```