# ASP MVC 5 Post a form from a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to make a custom data grid view with multi column filtering and pagination. so i made a view model winch will encapsulate three class

1. IEnumerable from the data.
2. Filter class with some properties
3. Pager to holder page size, current page, total pages etc ..

Filtering working fine but pagination not :(. as i loose the view model when pressing pagination link "It seems that i need to also submit the search form"
Any one can show how i can submit the form when pressing a link.
here is my view

```
@model TestFilteringAndPagination.ViewModels.CarViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@*Search form*@
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Pager.CurrentPage)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Pager.PageSize)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Pager.EndPage)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Pager.StartPage)
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Car No</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Filter.CarNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Line name</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Filter.LineName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    </div>
    <ul class="pagination">

        @for (var page = Model.Pager.StartPage; page <= Model.Pager.EndPage; page++)
        {
            <li class="@(page == Model.Pager.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
                <a href="#">@page</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}


@*Data grid*@
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Car number
            </th>
            <th>
                Car Line
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var car in Model.Cars)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => car.CarNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => car.LineName)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: An idea of the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294302/how-to-retain-data-form-on-custom-pagination-using-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can install the PagedList.MVC NuGet Package, see this post for more info about how to create exactly what you want.

[Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#add-paging-to-the-students-index-page)